# MSInfo32 command line switches and Windows 10 issue checking remote PC

Tags: windows-10, batch-file

I am trying to run MSInfo32 on a list of hostnames using the command line switches:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (hosts.txt) do (
    start /wait msinfo32 /nfo %%A /computer %%A
)
```

It appears to work well except when a remote host is offline, is not running the WMI service, or I'm not a local admin (some users...). When any of those issues occur, it collects the info from the local machine and saves it to the file instead. The only [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490937.aspx) I can [find](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/300887) on [MSInfo32](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/msinfo.mspx?mfr=true) is from Windows XP or earlier. Anyone know how to make MSInfo32 work as intended?